# Qual a melhor forma de fazer um streaming ao vivo que funcione em todos os navegadores?

Tags: nginx, streaming

Já fiz no passado sistemas em RTMP com o Wowza para fazer transmissões ao vivo, mas eu usava um player em flash.

Agora preciso fazer transmissões novamente, mas não quero usar flash, quero usar a tag video do HTML5 e gostaria que funcionasse em todos os navegadores mais populares (desktop: chrome, firefox, IE, Safari / Mobile: Chrome, Safari).

Qual a melhor abordagem? Já pesquisei sobre o Nginx e Wowza mas não achei nada. Estava procurando soluções para servidores Windows mas a essa altura já estou ebrto para soluções Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Se estiver aberto a usar PaaS - Platform as a Service - recomendo experimentar [Azure Media Services](https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/services/media-services/).

Com ele você poderá criar canais de transmissão ao vivo, cada canal irá criar um *endpoint*/URL onde irá incluir no player da sua página web.

Para o player, recomendo que use o [Azure Media Player](http://ampdemo.azureedge.net/azuremediaplayer.html). Um player feito com HTML5, que suporta todo tipo de streaming, progressivo, adaptivo, live, etc.